# FCM structure with Cloud Functions Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

I need to send some data from one user to another. Once a user sends that data, the other user can either decline or accept it. Now, I have a couple of questions. How should I be structuring my database to store FCM tokens? Should the tokens be under a node such as users/{username}? If that is the case, then when a user sends another user the data, I should be iterating through users/{username} to find that specific username, and get the token, correct? Then, once I have that token, I can push it along with the sender username and the data that I want to send to Firebase in a node like shareWorkout/{id}. My index.js looks like this

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

//Create and Deploy Your First Cloud Functions
//https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/write-firebase-functions

const admin = requre('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.sendNotification = functions.database
.ref("shareWorkout/{id}")
.onWrite(event => {
 var request = event.data.val();

 var payload = {
     data:{
         senderId: request.id,
         workout: request.workout
     }
 };

 admin.messaging().sendToDevice(request.token, payload)

})
```

Am I on the right track here?

Comment: This code looks quite far from what you're describing. If you're new to the Firebase Database, JavaScript, or both, Cloud Functions for Firebase is not the easiest way to learn it. I recommend first reading the [Firebase documentation for Web developers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start) and/or taking the [Firebase codelab for Web developers](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-web/). They cover many basic JavaScript, Web and Firebase interactions. After those you'll be much better equipped to write code for Cloud Functions too.